# Powershell lambda scope

Tags: powershell, scope, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to use a higher-order function to perform a certain task, but it seems that the scope isn't working as I expected. The code is as follows:

```bsh
function DoSomething($scriptBlock, $message) {

    # if not only running a check, run the given code
    if ($shouldRunCheck) {
       return $scriptBlock.Invoke()
    }

    Write-Host $message -foreground cyan
    # write $message to file
}
```

This seems to work fine, but when I call it I don't seem to be able to save to variables outside of the script block.

```bsh
$myArray = @()
$myArray += 'test 1'

DoSomething {
   write-host $myArray # test 1
   $myArray += 'test 2'

   write-host $myArray # test 2
}

write-host $myArray # test 1
$myArray += 'test 3'
write-host $myArray # test 1 test 3
```

Essentially I'm need to add to the array variable from within the callback function but it just seems to over-write the variable as if the variable is read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+1` for [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) explanation, I would although try to avoid to use the `$Global:` and the `$Script:` scopes as they might get confusing.
It is also possible to refer to the current scope of the caller by using `([Ref]$myArray).Value`:

```
function DoSomething($scriptBlock) {
    return $scriptBlock.Invoke()
}

$myArray = @('test 1')
$scriptBlock = {
    ([Ref]$myArray).Value += 'test 2'
}

DoSomething $scriptBlock

$myArray += 'test 3'
Write-Host $myArray
test 1 test 2 test 3
```

But the explanation from [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) also implies that the use `+=` on a PowerShell array is a bad idea as you will recreate the array each time which is just slow.

In other words for a better performance, it is better to use an `ArrayList` and the `Add` method rather than assigning items:

```
function DoSomething($scriptBlock) {
    return $scriptBlock.Invoke()
}

$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$myArray.Add('test 1')
$scriptBlock = {
    $myArray.Add('test 2')
}

DoSomething $scriptBlock

$myArray.Add('test 3')
Write-Host $myArray
test 1 test 2 test 3
```

You might also consider to use the mighty PowerShell pipeline for something like this:

```
$scriptBlock = {
    'test 2'
}

$myArray = @(
    'test 1'
    DoSomething $scriptBlock
    'test 3'
)
Write-Host $myArray
test 1 test 2 test 3
```

Comment: The `([Ref]$myArray).Value += 'test 2'` option is a good shout.

Comment: adding ([ref] ...) does not work for me, the variable is still set to 0 (I use integers instead of strings)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about the [Scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

What happens is that inside the scriptblock, the variable `$myArray` is created new as type [String] when `$myArray += 'test 2'` is performed. This new variable does not exist outside the function, so the original `$myArray` is not altered at all.

To do that, you need to use scoping on the `$myArray` and declare it as `$script:myArray = @('test 1')` so it can be accessed throughout the entire script.
Then inside the scriptblock you add the new value to it using `$script:myArray += 'test 2'`, like:

```
function DoSomething($scriptBlock) {
    return $scriptBlock.Invoke()
}

$script:myArray = @('test 1')                # declared in script-scope

# while inside the main script, you can simply access it as $myArray
Write-Host "MainScript:  $myArray"           # --> test 1   

$scriptBlock = {
   Write-Host "ScriptBlock: $script:myArray" # --> test 1
   $script:myArray += 'test 2'

   Write-Host "ScriptBlock: $script:myArray" # --> test 1 test 2
}

DoSomething $scriptBlock

Write-Host "MainScript:  $myArray"          # --> test 1 test 2
$myArray += 'test 3'
Write-Host "MainScript:  $myArray"          # --> test 1 test 2 test 3
```

Result:

> ```
> MainScript:  test 1
> ScriptBlock: test 1
> ScriptBlock: test 1 test 2
> MainScript:  test 1 test 2
> MainScript:  test 1 test 2 test 3
> ```